# Nested repeating stream filtering

Tags: java, java-stream

I am learning Java streams and have a situation where I need to use different filter on a stream in case filtering with the first filter didn't return any results. Currently I have this, thinking if there is a better way to write this:

```
String str = requestParams.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("string1") && e.getValue().length() > 0)
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst().orElseGet(() -> requestParams.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("string2") && e.getValue().length() > 0)
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .findFirst().orElse(""));
```

Comment: _Nitpicking_ here so take it with a pinch of salt. it would be better to reverse the filter logic to check for `e.getValue().length() > 0` before `e.getKey().contains("string1")` i.e. `e.getValue().length() > 0 && e.getKey().contains("string1")`

Answer (score 1):

As you want to search the entire source for this criteria `e.getKey().contains("string1") && e.getValue().length() > 0` and only then if it's not met then you want to do another search for `e.getKey().contains("string2") && e.getValue().length() > 0` I would say your current approach is fine but just encapsulate the logic into a method so you DRY i.e.

```
static Optional<String> getValueByX(Map<String, String> requestParams, String searchString) {
       return requestParams.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(searchString) && 
                             e.getValue().length() > 0)
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .findFirst();
}
```

Then you would call it as:

```
String result = getValueByX(requestParams, "string1")
                .orElseGet(() -> getValueByX(requestParams, "string2").orElse(""));
```

*However*, if you don't care about searching for "string1" in the entire source before applying the criteria for "string2" then you're better of doing:

```
String str = requestParams.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> (e.getKey().contains("string1") || e.getKey().contains("string2")) && e.getValue().length() > 0)
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst().orElse("")
```

if there could be more options than the aforementioned two then I would create a list to contain those values and then perform:

```
List<String> search = Arrays.asList("string1", "string2"..........);
String result = requestParams.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .filter(e -> search.stream().anyMatch(a -> e.getKey().contains(a)) &&
                             e.getValue().length() > 0)
             .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
             .findFirst().orElse("");
```

Comment: I think, the OP does care about searching all keys for the first string first. By the way, I’d replace `e.getValue().length() > 0` with `!e.getValue().isEmpty()`. But since the subsequent `map` step calls `getValue` anyway, you may use `.filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(searchString)) .map(Map.Entry::getValue).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `Collectors.teeing` method by processing two streams in parallel and filtering.  This returns an `Optional` and will be either `s1`, `s2`, or `Non-existent` depending on the `map` contents.

This presumes that you want to favor `string1` before accepting `string2`

```
Map<String, String> requestParams = Map.of("string1","s1","string3",
   "s3", "string2", "s2", "string4","s4"); 


Optional<String> op = requestParams.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().length() > 0)
        .collect(Collectors.teeing(Collectors.filtering(
                e -> e.getKey().contains("string1"),
                Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> a)),
                Collectors.filtering(
                        e -> e.getKey().contains("string2"),
                        Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> a)),
                (opt1, opt2) -> opt1.or(() -> opt2)
                        .map(Entry::getValue)));

System.out.println(op.orElse("Non Existent"));
```

The above use of `Collectors.teeing` was modified to incorporate suggestion by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) to use `Collectors.reducing` to get first item.

Comment: Why not use `reducing((a,b) -> a)` instead of `toList()` when you care for the first element only? Then, you can simplify the merger to `(opt1,opt2) -> opt1.or(() -> opt2).map(Map.Entry:: getValue)`

Comment: I will try it but it never occurred to me. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can check both conditions simultaneously, since the other logic is the same:

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("string1", "string2");
requestParams.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> keys.contains(e.getKey()) && e.getValue().length() > 0)
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findFirst().orElse("");
```

Comment: 1) `keys.contains(e.getKey())`... OPs code is not checking if `e.getKey()` is in either "string1" or  "string2" rather the opposite. 2) I believe OP wants to check the entire source for `e.getKey().contains("string1")` before doing it for `e.getKey().contains("string2")`

Comment: _assuming_ OP doesn't want to check the entire source for `e.getKey().contains("string1")` before doing it for `e.getKey().contains("string2")` then your solution would be valid with this change to filter pred `keys.stream().anyMatch(a -> e.getKey().contains(a)) && e.getValue().length() > 0` rather than the current one.